# How can I make a Pandas Series with a MultiIndex axes value take a DatetimeIndex for reindexing?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader, tiingo

Still a bit new to Pandas so I am trying to follow this tutorial here:
https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-finance-part-yahoo-finance-api-pandas-matplotlib/

However, it seems a bit dated and I had to convert the data feed to pull from Tiingo instead. Otherwise trying to follow the tutorial as is and I run into an exception every time on the reindex call. Here's the exception:

```
...site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 483, in from_tuples
arrays = list(lib.tuples_to_object_array(tuples).T)
TypeError: Argument 'tuples' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DatetimeArray)
```

Here's my version of the code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

start_date = '2019-8-27'
end_date = '2019-8-30'

panel_data = pdr.get_data_tiingo('GLD', start=start_date, end=end_date, api_key='[REDACTED]')
close = panel_data['close']
all_weekdays = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='B')
close = close.reindex(all_weekdays)
```

The tutorial makes it seem like everything up to this point should just work, but I get the TypeError exception on that `reindex()` call. **Why?**

I did try throwing a `.to_numpy()` after `all_weekdays` to satisfy the exception message but it still gives me the same exception including saying that it's a DatetimeArray.

Debugging so far makes me think that it's having issues because the `close` series axes is set to a MultiIndex containing both symbol and date columns as the print output shows here.

```
[MultiIndex([('GLD', '2019-08-27 00:00:00+00:00'),
            ('GLD', '2019-08-28 00:00:00+00:00'),
            ('GLD', '2019-08-29 00:00:00+00:00'),
            ('GLD', '2019-08-30 00:00:00+00:00')],
           names=['symbol', 'date'])]
```

This might make it have problems if it's reindexing against a simple list of dates in the form of the DatetimeIndex that is `all_weekdays`.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-27', '2019-08-28', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Do I need to coerce one index to match the other before reindexing? If so, how would I go about doing this? If not, what's an equivalent workaround to unblock me in this tutorial?

Comment: I don't even get past `pdr.get_data_tiingo('GLD', start=start_date, end=end_date, api_key='[REDACTED]')`. That line gives me an error `TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not None`. That makes me think, that the code is indeed outdated.

Comment: Just to make sure it's the tutorial code and not you, did you register an account with Tiingo and get your own API key? Their API is free to use but it does require auth to use.

Comment: That could be the reason of course. I didn't register, but I wouldn't like to unless I need the data for something else as answering questions here.